# How to generate a point using a method?

Tags: java, methods

How to generate a point using a method? I want to calculate the distance between 2 points.

```
public double getPointA(double x, double y){
    return getPointA(x,y);
}


 public double getPointB(double x, double y){
    return getPointB(x,y);
}


 public double length(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    double x = Math.pow(x2-x1,2);
    double y = Math.pow(x1-y1,2);
    double l = Math.sqrt(x+y);
    return l;         
}
```

Comment: Look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html

Comment: it compiles now after some changes

Comment: Okay, now why do you need a Point class at all? You're directly using the distance method

Answer (score 0):

Your methods are

1. Returning a `double`, which is not a `Point`.
2. Calling themselves endlessly. This is called infinite recursion, but don't worry about that for now.

You can make a method return a built-in Point class with `return new Point2D.Double(x, y)`.

[All `Point2D` objects already have a `distance()` method that accepts another `Point2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance(java.awt.geom.Point2D)).

```
public double getDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return getPointA(x1, y1).distance(getPointB(x2, y2));
}
```

Comment: is there another alternative? because it can't compile "package Point2D does not exist"

Comment: @Jarvis It is not a package, it is a class. The alternative is defining your own Point class, of course

Answer (score 0):

There's a class called `Point2D.Double` which does what you're after.  So you can write something like

```
Point2D.Double myPoint = new Point2D.Double(1.5, 2.8);
```

for example.  You can easily find the distance between two of these objects.

```
double distance = myPoint.distance(yourPoint);
```

Comment: is there another alternative? because it can't compile "package Point2D does not exist"

Comment: You need to import the Point2D class.